# New Facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

I have an application that uses require_login. I created a new application for test purposes, but it doesn't work. It stops at:

```
$fb->require_login($required_permissions = 'email,publish_stream');
```

So my question is, the new applications must use the new php sdk?

Comment: how does it "stop"? I mean, what errors do you get?

Comment: Don't bother looking for the errors, just use the new PHP-SDK...(btw it's not a must, you can create your own but of course it's recommended!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks, sorry about the delay in response. I noticed that the configuration application options are different at the production application and the test application. Production app has more options to configure, because it's has been registered so long time ago. So I tried selecting/deselecting different options,  and now it works.